Can't access to widget second time
I have a AScoreboardWidget
ScoreboardWidget.h
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "ScoreboardWidget.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class FLY_BIRD_FLY_API AScoreboardWidget : public AActor {
    GENERATED_BODY()

    public:
        // Sets default values for this actor's properties
        AScoreboardWidget();

    protected:
        // Called when the game starts or when spawned
        virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    public:
        // Called every frame
        virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

        void SetScore(int Score);

    private:
        UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, Category = "Category")
        class UUserWidget* Scoreboard;

};

ScoreboardWidget.cpp
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "ScoreboardWidget.h"
#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "Components/TextBlock.h"
#include "Internationalization/Text.h"

// Sets default values
AScoreboardWidget::AScoreboardWidget() {
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AScoreboardWidget::BeginPlay() {
    Super::BeginPlay();

    Scoreboard->AddToViewport();

    Cast<UTextBlock>(Scoreboard->GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("ScoreText")))->SetText(
        FText::FromString("Score is: 0")
    );
}

// Called every frame
void AScoreboardWidget::Tick(float DeltaTime) {
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
}

void AScoreboardWidget::SetScore(int Score) {
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Score: %d"), Score);
    
    if (auto x = Scoreboard) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Scoreboard found"));
    } else {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Scoreboard not found"));

        return;
    }

    if (auto x = Scoreboard->GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("ScoreText"))) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Widget found"));
    } else {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Widget not found"));

        return;
    }
    
    Cast<UTextBlock>(Scoreboard->GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("ScoreText")))->SetText(
        FText::FromString("Score is: 1")
    );

    // Cast<UTextBlock>(Scoreboard->GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("ScoreText")))->SetText(
    //  FText::FromString(
    //      FString::Printf(TEXT("Score is: %d"), Score)
    //  )
    // );
}

Also I have a ABird class which uses this widget
Bird.h
...
public:
        ...
        void SetScore(int NewScore);

private:
        ...
        UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, Category = "Components")
        TSubclassOf<AScoreboardWidget> ScoreboardWidget;
...

Bird.cpp
...
void ABird::SetScore(int NewScore) {
    Score = NewScore;
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Score: %d"), Score);
    ScoreboardWidget->GetDefaultObject<AScoreboardWidget>()->SetScore(Score);
}
...

Here is more info on screenshots:




So as you can see I can access to widget inside of BeginPlay but not inside of SetScore. What is the problem?
